# Проверьте пожалуйста - "некстати"

Tags: синтаксис

*Когда они остались наедине, он спросил у нее **некстати**, была ли она когда-нибудь неверна супругу.*

*некстати* выражено наречием; синтаксическая функция - обстоятельство образа действия?

Спасибо!

Comment: Похоже, что так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формально это обстоятельства образа действия (по  общепринятой классификации), но по сути я бы назвала его обстоятельством **соответствия, уместности** действия.

Обстоятельство образа действия обычно определяют качество или способ действия, а здесь мы имеем дело с оценкой действия (кстати, некстати, напрасно, зря и т.д).

Но получается так, что все обстоятельства, семантику которых сложно определить, относят к обстоятельствам образа действия.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, Вера. Я тоже об этом думал. Но никак, кроме об-ство о/д это не назовешь.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это обстоятельство образа действия. Спросил как?